# Finding inverse of a general linear transform

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, inverse, linear-transformations

I'm not a mathematician, so I may abuse some notation here. Please comment for any clarification.

Let's define a general linear transform as

$$\int_XK(\mathbf{\omega},x)f(x)dx$$

where $X$ is some region, and both $x$ and $\omega$ can be vectors. In some usual cases, such as those of Laplace and Fourier transforms, $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\omega \in \mathbb{R} \text{ or } \mathbb{C}$, and $X = (-\infty, \infty)$. In case of a wavelet transform, $\omega$ is represented by two numbers, namely scale and shift.

My question is, given the transfomration kernel $K(\omega, x)$, and given that the transformation is invertible, is there a standard way of finding its inverse kernel $\bar{K}(\omega,x)$ such that

$$\int_\Omega \bar{K}(\omega, x)\left(\int_XK(\mathbf{\omega},y)f(y)dy\right)d\omega = f(x)$$
with some reasonable constraints, e.g. $f(x)$ behaves well in some sense, or perhaps the equivalence holds almost everywhere?

I understand that this question may be a bit generic, but perhaps there are some special cases for which this is easy? For example, if $K(\omega, x)$ is a unitary transformation, then finding the inverse transform is nearly trivial. Are there other such cases? At the very least, where should I look?

Comment: One touchstone example is the Fourier Transform. The easiest way to find its inverse is to show that $\mathcal{F}^2(f)(x) = f(-x)$

Comment: In general you can't even assume that the transform is bijective. Given that it is, I do not know of a general procedure. Have you seen [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/93595/general-procedure-for-inverse-of-an-integral-transform)?

Comment: @MattL. Good find. I think this is essentially a dupe then. Should I close it?

Comment: @Phonon: I think it's a relevant and natural question (even though there might be no satisfactory answer to it). You're probably not the last one to wonder about it, so I think it does have some right to remain on this site.